# Safely Evaluating Input of Multiple Types - OPA Gatekeeper/Rego

Tags: kubernetes, opa, kubernetes-apiserver, rego

I'm trying to deploy a Constraint Template to my Kubernetes cluster for enforcing `PodDisriptionBudgets` contain a `maxUnavailable` percentage higher than a given percentage, and denying integer values.

However, I'm unsure how to safely evaluate `maxUnavailable` since it can be **an integer or a string**. Here is the constraint template I am using:

```
apiVersion: templates.gatekeeper.sh/v1beta1
kind: ConstraintTemplate
metadata:
  name: pdbrequiredtolerance
spec:
  crd:
    spec:
      names:
        kind: PdbRequiredTolerance
      validation:
        # Schema for the `parameters` field
        openAPIV3Schema:
          properties:
            minAllowed:
              type: integer
  targets:
    - target: admission.k8s.gatekeeper.sh
      rego: |
        package pdbrequiredtolerance

        # Check that maxUnavailable exists
        violation[{"msg": msg }] {
          not input.review.object.spec.maxUnavailable
          msg := "You must use maxUnavailable on your PDB"
        }

        # Check that maxUnavailable is a string
        violation[{"msg": msg}] {
          not is_string(input.review.object.spec.maxUnavailable)
          msg := "maxUnavailable must be a string"
        }

        # Check that maxUnavailable is a percentage
        violation[{"msg": msg}] {
          not endswith(input.review.object.spec.maxUnavailable,"%")
          msg := "maxUnavailable must be a string ending with %"
        }

        # Check that maxUnavailable is in the accpetable range
        violation[{"msg": msg}] {
          percentage := split(input.review.object.spec.maxUnavailable, "%")
          to_number(percentage[0]) < input.parameters.minAllowed
          msg := sprintf("You must have maxUnavailable of %v percent or higher", [input.parameters.minAllowed])
        }
```

When I enter a PDB with a value that's too high, I receive the expected error:

```
Error from server ([pdb-must-have-max-unavailable] You must have maxUnavailable of 30 percent or higher)
```

However, when I use a PDB with an integer value:

```
Error from server (admission.k8s.gatekeeper.sh: __modset_templates["admission.k8s.gatekeeper.sh"]["PdbRequiredTolerance"]_idx_0:14: eval_type_error: endswith: operand 1 must be string but got number)
```

This is because `endswith` rule is trying to evaluate a string. Is there any way around this in Gatekeeper? Both PDBs I specified are valid Kubernetes manifests. I do not wish to return this confusing error to our end users, and would rather clarify that they cannot use integers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this was solved elsewhere, but for posterity, one solution to this would be to simply convert the value of variable type to a known type (like string) before doing the comparison or operation.

```
maxUnavailable := sprintf("%v", [input.review.object.spec.maxUnavailable])
```

`maxUnavailable` can now safely be dealt with as a string regardless of the original type.